# Rails callout gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, callout

I'm developing a Rails app that needs to receive callouts (AKA "web requests") from a third-party service when an event occurs. Is there a gem or service that allows me to receive these from my development environment (which is not externally accessible by the internet)?

Comment: a callout is a web request from the 3rd party to a url you specify. For example Zencoder is a cloud media encoding service. When an item is finished encoding it can make a request to your server notifying you the job is done.

Comment: The term is "[callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29)". "callout" is  a publishing term. I'd recommend adjusting the question to use the correct word "callback".

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any third party gem, just send them your application url when the third party service completes their process they will invoke your url to inform your application that the processing is complete.

Comment: The problem is that my development environment is not externally accessible, and so cannot receive the web request.